# Haproxy monitor request response codes

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, haproxy, request

Is there a way to monitor Haproxy response stats in the Browser.

For example curl -x 127.0.0.1:4444 http://ifconfig.me —>response 200

Is there a way to monitor the request response codes in the build in stats feature of haproxy?

[enter image description here][1]

And how to view request logs in log file.

My haproxy.cfg file looks like this:

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSCR4.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSCR4.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yrOQ.jpg)

Haproxy running in a docker container, if run command docker logs container_id    I can see the log output but request reponse codes are not displayed, how to change cfg file to display response codes in docker logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse over underscored number in Sessions->Total and you will see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, i updated the post can you help me?

Comment: not sure if it will work with `option http_proxy` which you use, but add `option httplog` to change log format, which logs some HTTP stuff, including response status code

Comment: Thank you, it not work i will try the browser solution. One last question how can i unlimit the connection, session limit is 1024 after that it will not accept connections, i will unlimit session and maxconn how to do that, thank you

Comment: If i hover on the browser method it shows nothing